# How i can get twitter count now?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

In the past I used http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url={url} https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302 but now it url return error. Who now new twitter link for get twit count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this post, from the twitter blog](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform), the "TwitCount API" was removed, for multiple reasons.

There's an [ongoing discussion about this problem here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/clarification-about-share-counts-for-the-new-tweet-button/52868), in case you're interested, but the replies from the twitter developers make it sound like this is not coming back any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out http://opensharecount.com, it is a drop in replacement for the old URL